# Display a georeferenced image with click within image border in ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-online

I have multiple georeferenced images and their extents as polygon geometries.I would like to display the polygons as a reference layer and enable the image to be displayed in the map after a click in the corresponding polygon using ArcGIS Online.

Does anyone know if this is possible. I have only seen apps which show a URL which can open an external file which is displayed in the webbrowser window.

Answer (score 0):

ArcGIS Online built-in applications do not have any native route to display the image inside the polygon onclick.

With the built in functionality I would suggest the following solution:

Add each image to your AOGL portal as an independent item, and then add a field to the polygon layer that contains the html  tag for the related image item that is now hosted in agol. When you add this field to your pop-up in MapViewer the image will displace.

Example field value:
`<img src="image.link">`

Where `image.link` is the item link that can be located on the overview page of the image uploaded in AGOL.

You can host the images anywhere and reference them by link this way, but uploading the above method does not require any additional software or services.